# Aligning multiple functions

Tags: math-mode, equations, align, amsmath

I'm trying to put together some rather long equation within two cases. 
I need them to align and I've come so far:

```
\begin{align}
s(t)=
\begin{cases}
     &s_1(t)\\
     &s_2(t)\\
     &s_3(t)\\
     &s_4(t)\\
     &s_5(t)
\end{cases}
= 
\begin{cases} 
   &S \cdot k_1 \cdot\frac{t}{T}+S\:\dot k_3\dot\:\sin{(4\cdot\pi\cdot(\frac{t}{T}))}\\                    
   &S \cdot k_4+S\cdot k_5 \cdot(\frac{t}{T})+S\cdot k_6\cdot(\frac{t}{T})^2\\                             
   &S \cdot k_7+S\cdot k_8 \cdot(\frac{t}{T})+S\:\dot k_9\dot\:\sin{(4\cdot\pi\cdot(\frac{t}{T}))}\\       
   &S \cdot k_{10}+S\cdot k_{11}\cdot(\frac{t}{T})+S\cdot k_{12}\cdot(\frac{t}{T})^2\\                     
   &S \cdot k_{13}+S\cdot k_{14}\cdot(\frac{t}{T})+S\:\dot k_{15}\dot\:\sin{(4\cdot\pi\cdot(\frac{t}{T}))} 
\end{cases}
   t& \in [I_0,I_1] \\
   t& \in [I_1,I_2] \\
   t& \in [I_2,I_3] \\
   t& \in [I_3,I_4] \\
   t& \in [I_4,I_5] 
\end{align}
```

[image]

All in all as shown above it doesn't line up the way I thought it to do. Does anyone have a clue to why it doesn't succeed? it seems like there is plenty of space to the left of the equation for it to happen? 
the pagelayout is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=30mm,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\setlength{\parindent}{2em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! It seems that your table is to wide for your page layout. That we can help you, we need to see small but complete (compilable) document with your equation, which reproduce your problem.

Comment: And there is no way to sqeeze the equation a little to the left in order to make the whole eqaution stand within "one" line, without changing the page setup?

Comment: I can suggest you many solution how to write your equation, but they depends on your page layout, which is so far unknown.

Comment: Please merge both code fragments into one complete document!

Comment: sorry just getting to know the interface :)

Comment: You remarked, "it doesn't line up the way i thought it to be." What *should* the correct way be? A verbal description is ok. Please be specific, though.

Comment: Please also clarify whether you need five separate equation numbers or if one number for all 5 cases suffices.

Comment: It needs to be in "one" straight line, i dont see how i could specify that in any other way. the " \in equations is at the moment pushed down below the rest of the equation (it shouldn't be). There should only be one number for the equation, but that is not my question though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a bit an abuse of notation, but it's clearer than the version with the double big brace.

I also removed all `\cdot` symbols, because they're not used in the standard practice of mathematics, the juxtaposition of symbols is multiplication.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[left={s(t)=\empheqlbrace}]{align}
s_1(t) &= S  k_1 \frac{t}{T}+S k_3\sin\Bigl(4\pi\frac{t}{T}\Bigr)
  & t& \in [I_0,I_1] \\
s_2(t) &= S  k_4+S k_5 \frac{t}{T}+S k_6\Bigl(\frac{t}{T}\Bigr)^2
  & t& \in [I_1,I_2] \\
s_3(t) &= S k_7+S k_8 \frac{t}{T}+S k_9\sin\Bigl(4\pi\frac{t}{T}\Bigr)
  & t& \in [I_2,I_3] \\
s_4(t) &= S  k_{10}+S k_{11}\frac{t}{T}+S k_{12}\Bigl(\frac{t}{T}\Bigr)^2
  & t& \in [I_3,I_4] \\
s_5(t) &= S  k_{13}+S k_{14}\frac{t}{T}+S k_{15}\sin\Bigl(4\pi\frac{t}{T}\Bigr)
  & t& \in [I_4,I_5] 
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I propose this solution with the `empheq` package and the `alignat` environment. I also removed the unnecessary parentheses and used the mediumsized fractions from `nccmath` (to be loaded before empheq).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=30mm,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\setlength{\parindent}{2em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[left={s(t)=\begin{dcases}
     s_1(t)\\\vphantom{\Big)}
     s_2(t)\vphantom{\Big)^2}\\
  s_3(t)\vphantom{\Big)}\\
 s_4(t)\vphantom{\Big)^2}\\
 s_5(t)\vphantom{\Big)}
\end{dcases}=\empheqlbrace} ]{alignat=2}
   &S \cdot k_1 \cdot\mfrac{t}{T}+S\:\dot k_3\dot\:\sin \Bigl(4\cdot\pi\cdot\mfrac{t}{T}\Bigr) & & t \in [I_0,I_1] \\
   &S \cdot k_4+S\cdot k_5 \cdot\mfrac{t}{T}+S\cdot k_6\cdot\Bigl(\mfrac{t}{T}\Bigr)^{\!2} & & t \in [I_1,I_2] \\
   &S \cdot k_7+S\cdot k_8 \cdot\mfrac{t}{T}+S\:\dot k_9\dot\:\sin\Bigl(4\cdot\pi\cdot\mfrac{t}{T}\Bigr) & & t \in [I_2,I_3] \\
 &S \cdot k_{10}+S\cdot k_{11}\cdot\mfrac{t}{T}+S\cdot k_{12}\cdot\Bigl(\mfrac{t}{T}\Bigr)^{\!2} & & t \in [I_3,I_4] \\
 &S \cdot k_{13}+S\cdot k_{14}\cdot\mfrac{t}{T}+S\:\dot k_{15}\dot\:\sin{\Bigl(4\cdot\pi\cdot\mfrac{t}{T}\Bigr)} &\qquad & t \in [I_4,I_5]
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image: and the <code>alignat</code> environment]